# python and netCDF: limiting temperatures displayed to ones between certain cloud optical depths (tau)

Tags: python, netcdf

I am trying to create a list of all of the temperatures between certain latitudes, longitudes, and cloud optical depths. Here is my current code:

```
f = MFDataset(filenames)

latbounds = [ 32.5 , 48.5 ]

lonbounds = [ 235.5 , 245.5 ]

lats = f.variables['lat'][:]
lons = f.variables['lon'][:]

# latitude lower and upper index
latli = np.argmin( np.abs( lats - latbounds[0] ) )
latui = np.argmin( np.abs( lats - latbounds[1] ) ) 
# longitude lower and upper index
lonli = np.argmin( np.abs( lons - lonbounds[0] ) )
lonui = np.argmin( np.abs( lons - lonbounds[1] ) )  

temprSubset = f.variables['tc'][ : , latli:latui , lonli:lonui,]
```

Basically, I want temprSubset to have a optical depth parameter but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: It would help to identify the dataset that you are trying to access.

Comment: You should check out [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) for this sort of work.  You could do: `f = xr.open_mfdataset(filenames)`, followed by `f = f.sel(lon=slice(235.5, 245.5), lat=slice(32.5, 48.5))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mask/slice the temperature array based on some criteria on another array; there are several ways, but using [masked arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) from Numpy might be the easiest:

```
import netCDF4 as nc4
import numpy as np

f = nc4.Dataset('rico.default.0000000.nc')

ql  = f.variables['ql'][:,:]
thl = f.variables['thl'][:,:]

thl_masked = np.ma.masked_where(ql <= 0, thl)
```

In this example, `thl_masked` will still have the same dimensions as `thl`, but all temperatures not matching the criteria on `ql` are masked and excluded from statistics/plots, e.g.:

```
In [16]: thl.mean(), thl_masked.mean()
Out[16]: (305.64367534922985, 299.59578605886236)
```

If you need to get rid of the masked cells, that can easily be done with `thl_masked.compressed()`.